# css stretching background image sprite technique

Tags: css, background, background-image, sprite, stretch

I have a div with styling, and its width is dynamic.

```
<style>
#mydiv {
    background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/manda-pie/chocolate/icons-390.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    -moz-background-size: 448px 368px;
    background-size: 448px 368px;
}
</style>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

You see the div stretches if you stretch the browser window.
How to make the background image to be stretched right the same way as the div does?
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3dsgn/106/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/3dsgn/106/

use 
`-moz-background-size:100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Visit "[http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3%5fbackgrounds.asp)"

```
#mydiv
```

{background-size:100% 100%;}